# UWP c# reading Stream from StorageFile returns null. Why and how to fix?

Tags: c#, uwp, null, stream

I am trying to open a Stream from a StorageFile. However, I have tried several ways to program this and always seem to get stuck.

Currently, I am able to use a filepicker to get the storagefile, store its token and use that token to get to the storagefile again. But when I want to use the OpenStreamForReadAsync method, the result is a nullstream.

I tried an async method first, then a task (see code) but I can't figure out what is wrong. Can someone help me?

A strange thing is that the line `dummy = 1;' is never executed. The debugger steps to bool=breakpoint;

```
public class Workbook
    {
        private StorageFile exFile = null;
        private Stream stream = null;
        public SpreadsheetDocument exDoc = null;
        long dummy = 0;

        public Workbook(String faToken)
        {
            GetStreamFromToken(faToken);
            //GetStream(exFile);
            //exDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, false);
            //var test = exDoc.WorkbookPart.Parts;
            bool breakpoint = true;
        }

        async private void GetStreamFromToken(String faToken)
        {
            exFile = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(faToken);
            stream = await GetStream(exFile);
            dummy = 1;

        }

        public Task<Stream> GetStream(StorageFile exFile)
        {
            return exFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my mistake. I did not understand that await does not mean that the code waits for completion. So I have to use a wait method to wait for completion of a task.